# Rigging & animating a rolled chart?

Tags: animation, rigging

I am working on an animation in which character opens a chart. The Chart will be rolled like that :

[image: a]

I want to rig this kind of a rolled chart & want an opening animation after that chart will look like this:

[image: Chart]

I have no idea how to do that only simple short answer will be helpful... (is it possible to do that in blender or not?). Only Short answer will be helpful.

Comment: Yes, it's possible.

Comment: But how to do that? Any Help will be appreciated.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/50396/how-can-i-animate-a-mesh-moving-in-a-spiral-fashion

Comment: Yes that's what I need. It meets my question & thanks for help.