# How to roll a plane onto a cylnder (paper onto a toilet roll)

Tags: modeling, animation

We're trying to make an animation pretty much like toilet roll being wound onto a cylinder (but the cylinder is invisible)

We've managed to do this:
[image: Coil Start]
[image: Coiled]

by moving the planes along a spiral but really that means the coil is too wide at the beginning but the end result is good.

Is there another way to achieve this goal because I think what we are doing now is fundamentally flawed in its approach?

This is not the same as [How can I animate a mesh moving in a spiral fashion?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/50396/how-can-i-animate-a-mesh-moving-in-a-spiral-fashion) - this approach also rolls a plane onto a spiral. I'm trying to get the effect that a material rolls onto a cylinder like a cassette tape winding onto a reel. This is almost backwards from the spiral approach because the first fold should be the smallest ....

Comment: I can't seem to post a gif which shows the whole sequence. Hence the two images

Comment: Not a duplicate @DuarteFarrajotaRamos - that solution is the one I currently have but it does not properly imitate how paper might roll up in (for example) a toilet roll being wound onto a cardboard tube because it is just following a spiral

Comment: I see. You could animate the curve with shapekeys throughout the animation, thought it might not be trivial. Animation Nodes might help here. Also see techniques described here https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/76756/how-to-animate-winding-a-ribbon-onto-a-cylinder