# How to animate cash being counted by a cash counter?

Tags: animation, physics, bezier-curves, cloth-simulation

I need to make an animation of the cash flowing through the counter.

What would be the best way to do this?

I thought about starting with creating a bezier curve and adjusting it to make cash go through the counter to the counter wheels at the front and then I'd apply cloth physics to the cash and collision to the wheels so that money bends and is transported downwards where it's later pushed further by more cash.

Unfortunately, I've just started learning Blender and though I can successfully set up a curve and the cash follows it correctly, the physics part is more tricky. Cash constantly behaves unpredictably around the wheels. Usually resulting in going through the wheels rather than being nicely taken down.

[image: Money counter]

Comment: usually the bills move so fast (unless you watch it in slow-mo) that you might be able to get away with faking it somehow. How realistic do you want this to be?

Comment: Yeah, I suppose you're right! This won't be watched in slow-mo, so definitely we can fake some things.

Comment: Suggestion.  See video tutorials on easy topics regarding items you do not understand. Please show your work regarding the bill movement. Please show 1 - 3 bills in your image.  Something you can manage.  Perhaps a small gif or sequence of images produced by Blender.   Showing just the counting machine is of quite limited value.

Comment: Suggestion.  Show in your work a bill moving along a path for a few frames.  [Follow path constraint].  Then show your bill being deform and bending. [simple deform modifier].  You may also choose to give the reader  a visual reference with a link to something similar to your goal.  For example ... here is a bill counter video that is similar to what I want .... link.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/50396/how-can-i-animate-a-mesh-moving-in-a-spiral-fashion/50407#50407 is an example of some paper being deformed with [curve modifier]